# How can I list all Python requirements for a specific folder/package?

Tags: python, python-3.8

I have been working on a project for some time, writing Python scripts spontaneously as I needed them. I'd like to pick out some important ones and put them neatly into a package and then a git repository in a way which makes it easy for co-workers to use them. How can I find out all required Python packages for this specific collection of scripts (which is now a package itself), so I can list them in a `requirements.txt`? I read up on `pip freeze`, but this will list everything in the current virtual environment, more than is needed by the scripts I have collected in my new package.

Answer (score 4):

There is a module called pipreqs

**pip install pipreqs

pipreqs /GitHub/FolderName**

Reference : https://pypi.org/project/pipreqs/